# Is there any git management GUI?

Tags: git, commit

I want to edit git history: change commit's authors (someone they're marked incorrectly) etc.

Is there any GUI for git, focused not on "pull & push" current commit, but on history editing?

P.S. I use linux, so linux clients are preferrable, but i can start wine for it

Comment: Note that by rewriting commits, you are rewriting history (all commits following after it). If you have pushed those commits before, it's not advisable to do it, unless you know what you do.

Answer (score 4):

You could try one of these :

- [git-cola](http://git-cola.github.com/)
- [gitk](http://gitk.sourceforge.net/)
- [Giggle](https://live.gnome.org/giggle)

If you work with Eclipse IDE, there is the [EGit plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) .

Comment: useless. All these utilities are just commit-managers and history-viewers. I need history editor.

Answer (score 1):

in `git Bash` type `gitk`. Suppose its what you need

Answer (score 0):

If you can run [mono](http://mono-project.com/) on Linux, then I think [GitExtensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) is the best choice.

GitExtensions relies on command line git.

GitExtensions is actively developing and has many fancy functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop C# in Linux with [Monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/), there is a built-in git plugin based on [NGit](https://github.com/mono/ngit) library.

Monodevelop does not call command line git.